# Where does the pen draw in relation to x and y client position

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing, rectangles

When drawing a line with a pen of some width how is the width of the pen allocated in relation to the x y coordinates?

If I have a start x of 10 end x of 50 and a start y of 10 and a end y of 10 with a pen of 20. If I wanted to draw a line at y 11 would the pen width draw it's 20 up or down? Would the 20px of the pen at as a border and sit on top of the y or would it act as a box model and draw into the box?

I've got the same question when it comes to drawing rectangles. If i draw a rectangle of a width of 100px x 100px and a pen of 20px would this make my rectangle 120px by 120px or would my rectangle be 100px x 100px with 20px drawn around the interior of the rectangle?

See the image i've provide.

[image]

Comment: What did you see when you tested the scenarios yourself?

Comment: The pen seem to be splitting the difference.

Comment: Anyone at got any suggestions?

Comment: Use the Pen.Alignment property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pen is drawn of both sides of the nominal location, so add or subtract `width/2` to find the inner and outer edge of the line.

An example is shown here at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bssbs7z.aspx).

[image: rectangle]

Also this can be changed by setting the `.Alignment` property.

[image: inset rectange]

Comment: .Alignment, is perfect. Thank you!